# imagefttext() function (php) increases size of image

Tags: php, watermark

**Trying to put watermark to an image**

**Image Original Size** :- 10.8 MB

**After watermarking**:- **New Image Size**:- 37.9 MB

```
$text = "Afrophoto";
//the text i want as watermark

//create a new image

$newImg = imagecreatefromjpeg($image);

//set the watermark font color to red

$fontColor = imagecolorallocate($newImg, 255, 255, 255);
$font_file = 'fontArial.ttf';

list($width, $height) = getimagesize($image);

//write the watermark on the created image
imagefttext($newImg, 50, 50, $j, $i, $width - 100, $height - 100, $text);

//output the new image with a watermark to a file

imagejpeg($newImg,"uploads/".$_FILES[$field]['name'],100);


imagepng($newImg,"uploads/".$_FILES[$field]['name'].".png");

imagedestroy($newImg);
```

Comment: Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: are you increasing any height and with? can you provide your code here

Comment: Hi! I have provided the code now.

Answer (score 0):

Here I used Png image

**Actual size banned.png: 53.2KB**

**with watermark bbimage_3.png: 40.8 KB**

```
<?php
$imageURL = "banned.png";
list($width,$height) = getimagesize($imageURL);
$imageProperties = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
$targetLayer = imagecreatefrompng($imageURL);
imagecopyresampled($imageProperties, $targetLayer, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width, $height);
$WaterMarkText = 'CONFIDENTIAL';
$watermarkColor = imagecolorallocate($imageProperties, 191,191,191);
imagestring($imageProperties, 5, 130, 117, $WaterMarkText, $watermarkColor);
imagepng($imageProperties, 'bbimage_3.png');
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
imagepng ($imageProperties);
imagedestroy($targetLayer);
imagedestroy($imageProperties);
?>
```

**imagecopy:** This function copies source image onto destination image by overwriting destination image pixels.

While merging png images with transparent background as a watermark, imagecopymerge() function will not preserve transparency onto the destination. So, imagecopy() is preferable for image watermarking.

Comment: I am very thankful for the help.
But I can't use image as a watermark. Because the image will look very short when used a high resolution picture. I only have text as an option.